# how to get each child of an element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get each game of this betting website (https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/live) I've tried several things on selenium but I only managed to get the div with all the games combined, what I need is to get each row of games individually with their respective values

Then I want to get each value sorted to a variable from the real time data:

- block x (x for number of games)
- match (team1 and team 2)
- score (team1 score and team2 score)
- time
- odds (team1 odd and team2 odd)

my code:

```
matchs=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="appinner"]/div/div[1]/span/div/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/div')
for items in matchs:
    print(items.text)
```

but i don't get each game separately, only the whole block, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Don't post and delete the same question over and over. Not only is it against the general policy, but you'll be prevented from asking more questions because of your poor-questions to questions-asked ratio.

Answer (score -2):

If you search from the network panel you will find a json endpoint that has all that data.

[image]

Comment: yes I've already tried this way but I'd rather prefer to scrape the data on the website directly, I just need the right code to get each game in my block of all games

Comment: The "direct" way is to use the data from the endpoint before it gets mangled by react.

Comment: how to get there? I don't know anything about endpoints and json datas... I'm willing to listen and learn if you can provide any help about it